# No funciona consulta personalizada tras actualizar a la version Woocommerce 3.0

Tags: woocommerce

buenas.

Tengo una plantilla de wordpress personalizada por mi. Dentro de esa plantilla tengo modificado los ficheros del template de Woocommerce en principio es "myaccount/order.php". 
La ruta completa es "mi-theme/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/order.php"

Hice un código personalizado para hacer una consulta a la base de datos y me devolviera unos datos. En problema es que al actualizar a la nueva versión de "woocommerce 3.0" Ese código no me funciona y se queda el fondo en blanco.

Supongo que las funciones a la base de datos habran cambiado en la nueva versión de woocommerce 3.0.

El código es el siguiente

```
$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
) ) );

    if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>
        <table class="shop_table my_account_orders table-striped" width="100%">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                    <th class="order-date"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                    <th class="order-status"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                    <th class="order-total"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>
                    <th class="order-actions"> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody><?php
                foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                    $order = new WC_Order();

                    $order->populate( $customer_order );

                    $status     = get_term_by( 'slug', $order->status, 'shop_order_status' );
                    $item_count = $order->get_item_count();

                    ?><tr class="order">
                        <td class="order-number">
                            <a href="<?php echo $order->get_view_order_url(); ?>">
                                <?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="order-date">
                            <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>
                        </td>
                        <td class="order-status" style="text-align:left; white-space:nowrap;">
                            <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="order-total">
                            <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>
                        </td>
                        <td class="order-actions">
                            <?php
                                $actions = array();

                                if ( in_array( $order->status, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_payment', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                    $actions['pay'] = array(
                                        'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                        'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                    );
                                }

                                if ( in_array( $order->status, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                    $actions['cancel'] = array(
                                        'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) ) ),
                                        'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                    );
                                }

                                $actions['view'] = array(
                                    'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                    'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                                );

                                $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order );

                                if ($actions) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <?php
                        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                            $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', $order->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );

                            wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-item.php', array(
                                'order'              => $order,
                                'item_id'            => $item_id,
                                'item'               => $item,
                                'show_purchase_note' => $show_purchase_note,
                                'purchase_note'      => $product ? get_post_meta( $product->id, '_purchase_note', true ) : '',
                                'product'            => $product,
                            ) );
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_order_items_table', $order ); ?>
                    <?php

                }
            ?></tbody>
            <tbody>

        </tbody>

        </table>
```

He probado a realizar cambios en el código pero ninguno me funciona. Necesito ayuda a ver que puede estar pasando. O si han cambiado el codigo y necesito alguna función nueva.

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos